# Text color can not be made white

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I have the following JSX code:

```
  <div style={Object.assign({}, styles.occupyAllScreen, styles.backgroundContainer)}>
    <div styles={styles.overimposingText}>
      <h2 styles={{color: 'white !important'}}>
        Hi everyone!
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Where the styles used are these:

```
const styles = {
  occupyAllScreen: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  },
  backgroundContainer: {
    position: 'relative',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center'
  },
  overimposingText: {
    position: 'absolute',
    color: 'white !important'
  }
};
```

As it can be seen, I specified `color: 'white !important'` both in the `h2` containning the text and the enclosing `div`.

However, the component still looks like this:

[image]

Any idea why the text can not be made white?

I made a fiddle for it [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/101262/)

Comment: styles={styles.overimposingText} ? or style={styles.overimposingText}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

correct syntax

```
<h2 style={{color: 'white'}}>
      Hi everyone!
    </h2>
```